# Create a black frame around an image

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to create a black frame around an image. Unfortunately, I've got the following error.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape (562,562)
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc
import scipy.misc

im = sc.misc.ascent()

blackFrame= np.zeros((im.shape[0]+100,im.shape[1]+100))
blackFrame[50:,50:] = im[:,:]
plt.imshow(blackFrame, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=250)
plt.show()
```

It works when I write `blackFrame[100:,100:] = im[:,:]` but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help: `blackFrame[50:50+im.shape[0],50:50+im.shape[1]] = im[:,:]`